# How to make motionless table header row?

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

This code works, but I need to adjust the sizes of header fields and the remaining table. How it is possible to adjust the size of columns?

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table_hsv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/table_header_row"
            android:background="@color/listcolor" >
        </TableRow>
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/table_sv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/table_data"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:stretchColumns="1" >
            </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, and what you've got currently. Can you give us some more information?

Comment: I need to display the table, the title should be fixed. The width of title should coincide with field width of the data.

Comment: I am sorry, I have found the problem resolution.
https://github.com/StylingAndroid/ScrollingTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, I have found the problem resolution.
https://github.com/StylingAndroid/ScrollingTable